# White line at the end of QComboBox. What's the reason?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qcombobox

QT 5.11 GCC

Problem code:

```
QStringList::const_iterator it_first = Ranks.cbegin();
QStringList::const_iterator it_second = RanksICO.cbegin();
while (it_first!=Ranks.cend() || it_second!=RanksICO.cend())
{
    m_rankComboBox->addItem(QIcon(*it_second), *it_first);
    ++it_first;
    ++it_second;
}
```

m_rankComboBox- is my qComboBox. RanksICO and Ranks are QStringList

```
static const QStringList Ranks={    "Рядовой",
                                "Ефрейтор",
                                "Младший сержант",
                                "Сержант",
                                "Старший сержант",
                                "Старшина",
                                "Прапорщик",
                                "Старший прапорщик",
                                "Младший лейтенант",
                                "Лейтенант",
                                "Старший лейтенант",
                                "Капитан",
                                "Майор",
                                "Подполковник",
                                "Полковник",
                                "Генерал-майор",
                                "Генерал-лейтенант",
                                "Генерал-полковник", };


static const QStringList RanksICO={ ":/images/Звания/Рядовой",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Ефрейтор",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Младший-сержант",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Сержант",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Старший-сержант",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Старшина",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Прапорщик",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Старший-прапорщик",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Младший-лейтенант",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Лейтенант",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Старший-лейтенант",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Капитан",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Майор",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Подполковник",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Полковник",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Генерал-майор",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Генерал-лейтенант",
                                    ":/images/Звания/Генерал-полковник", };
```

I view this result:

[image]

I used to think that it's the empty item, but it's false.

Question again: Why i see white line at the end of QComboBox?

Max index is 17 and `qDebug()<< m_rankComboBox->count();`  returns me 17

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you select the last line?
Do you use stylesheets (maybe a style somehow makes the popup larger than it should be for its content)

Comment: replace ++it_first; with it_first++;

Comment: QComboBox also has an [addItems](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#addItems) method directly accepting QStringList, and you can add the icons in a loop afterwards maybe?
also, `while (it_first!=Ranks.cend() || it_second!=RanksICO.cend())` should probably read `while (it_first!=Ranks.cend() && it_second!=RanksICO.cend())` - if they are not the same length, you want to finish if any of the two is at its end, otherwise you will go past its end

Answer (score 0):

It's happened because you add icons to your combo box, and get it unsuitable size.
Try to edit `setIconSize` parameter in `QComboBox` class

```
m_rankComboBox->setIconSize(QSize(width, heigt));
```